# Socket read takes lot of time

Tags: java, sockets

Below is my client code where I am doing Socket write & read operations. Here I am interacting with server with which the protocol is already defined. Accordingly we are sending code messages to it and reading the responses. However in below code:

```
message_id = din.readInt();
```

This line runs for a long time and returns data after 15 mins. I am not sure why it takes that much time please let me know if anyone faced this issue before.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ConnectSaS {

    public static final int REQ_SESOPEN = 128;

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket;

        DataOutputStream out;
        int message_id;
        int persist_session_id;
        int session_id;
        int data_length;
        String connectionString;

        try {
            socket = new Socket("infasas", 11080);
            socket.setSoTimeout(0);
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            socket.isOutputShutdown();          

            System.out.println("Connection accepted " + socket.getInetAddress()
                    + ":" + socket.getPort() + ":" + socket.getLocalPort());

            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeInt(REQ_SESOPEN);
            out.writeInt(6);
            out.writeInt(40);
            connectionString = "sasuser sasuser SAS_Connection IS_ps7153";          
            out.write(connectionString.getBytes());

            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            message_id = din.readInt();
            persist_session_id = din.readInt();
            data_length = din.readInt();
            din.readByte();
            System.out.println("message_id:----" + message_id);
            System.out.println("session_id:----" + persist_session_id);
            System.out.println("data_length:----" + data_length);   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading back from server: " + e);
        }   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes that much time because it takes the sender that much time to send you the integer.

Calling `isOutputShutdown()` and throwing away the result is completely pointless.